# Magento error Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in

Tags: templates, slider, magento-1.9

I use Magneto 1.9.2 with template intenso... Intenso have many kind of modules - sliders, screen of product, bannerslider, productslider.. I have a bannerslider, but if i make a change, magento fall down with error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /home/dev/web/app/code/local/Itactica/LogoSlider/Model/Resource/Slider/Logos.php on line 33

All Code is:

```
public function saveLogosRelation($slider, $data){
    if (!is_array($data)) {
        $data = array();
    }
    $deleteCondition = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->quoteInto('slider_id=?', $slider->getId());
    $this->_getWriteAdapter()->delete($this->getMainTable(), $deleteCondition);

    foreach ($data as $logoId => $info) {
        $this->_getWriteAdapter()->insert($this->getMainTable(), array(
            'slider_id' => $slider->getId(),
            'logo_id' => $logoId,
            'position'   => @$info['position']
        ));
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Row 33 is

```
 $this->_getWriteAdapter()->insert($this->getMainTable(), array(
                'slider_id' => $slider->getId()
```

,

Can I find how to repair this getIt method..?
I try all things, but it not working still. Can you help me ? Thanks..;)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please do one thing.In the following function after either `print_r($slider)` or `var_dump($slider)`. Then try to find whether id is data member of the slider object or not.

```html
public function saveLogosRelation($slider, $data){

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($slider); // here you will get display all data member of slider then you will get idea how to get id
    
    exit;
    
    if (!is_array($data)) {
        $data = array();
    }
    $deleteCondition = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->quoteInto('slider_id=?', $slider->getId());
    $this->_getWriteAdapter()->delete($this->getMainTable(), $deleteCondition);

    foreach ($data as $logoId => $info) {
        $this->_getWriteAdapter()->insert($this->getMainTable(), array(
            'slider_id' => $slider->getId(),
            'logo_id' => $logoId,
            'position'   => @$info['position']
        ));
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Let me know if you have still any query

Thanks